# Flutter : How to clear Firebase cache after logging out from app?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

I'm trying to clear the Firebase Cache after a user logs out from the app. I've already tried this but the code clears all my files it seems because I had background images before logging out and all those images disappeared after logging out.

```
void clearCache() async{
var appDir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
new Directory(appDir).delete(recursive: true); }
```

This is not the effect I want. I merely just want to clear the Firebase Cache and retain the rest of my app files. How would I go about achieving this ?

Here are the logout code snippets

```
new FlatButton(
          child: new Text("Yes",style: new TextStyle(fontFamily: 'DroidSansChinese', color: Colors.white),),
          onPressed: () {_signOut(); clearPreferences();clearCache();},
        ),

void _signOut() async {
await _auth.signOut();
Navigator.of(context)
    .pushAndRemoveUntil(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginPage()), (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

}

```
void clearPreferences() async{
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
await prefs.setString('name', '');
await prefs.setString('surname', '');
await prefs.setString('email', '');
await prefs.setString('id', '');
print(prefs.getString('name'));
```

}

```
void clearCache() async{
var appDir = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;
new Directory(appDir).delete(recursive: true);
```

}

Comment: I believe firebase cache will disappear once you unsubscribe from the listeners.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of the behavior of Firebase cache once you do unsubscribe from the listeners. The reason why I want to implement the clearance in my app is to be completely sure that I'm getting rid of all of the previous users information.

Comment: FirebaseFirestore.clearPersistence() not yet available I guess https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58902649/how-to-clear-firebase-cache

Answer (score 1):

> but the code clears all my files

Checking the snippets you've provided, the files created by the app are deleted with `Directory(appDir).delete(recursive: true);`. What you have here is clearing SharedPreferences that you've stored, not necessarily clearing cache created by Firebase.

[Signing out](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/signOut.html) from FirebaseAuth should clear the user instance. Instead of storing user details in SharedPreferences, user details can be easily fetched while the user is logged-in with `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser`. This returns [User class](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User-class.html) containing user details.

```dart
var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
String? name = user.displayName;
String? email = user.email;
String? id = user.uid;
```