# How to properly call FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence() in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm facing the same problem as this guy [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58902649/how-to-clear-firebase-cache/58902735#58902735)

But his accepted answer didn't helped me.

**The problem:**

When an user signs out, and another different user signs in, all data shown on my app is from the previous signed out user due to firebase caching system. I searched about this issue and found a solution that consists in calling this method:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();
```

But everytime and everywhere I place this line of code, throws an exception saying I cannot call this method when the client is running:

> Exception has occurred.
> PlatformException (PlatformException(failed-precondition, Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console., {code: failed-precondition, message: Operation was rejected because the system is not in a state required for the operation's execution. If performing a query, ensure it has been indexed via the Firebase console., nativeErrorMessage: Persistence cannot be cleared while the client is running., nativeErrorCode: 9}))

so, how to call this method? or better, is there a best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 21):

It seems it's necessary to terminate the `FirebaseFirestore.instance` first.

At the end of my log off method I call:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.terminate();
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();
```

I get no errors thrown and everything seems to be working as it should now.

Answer (score 1):

You should call it immediately after you initialize Firebase, and before you make the first query.

Comment: I tried that approach and it didn't work. I logged off, and placed await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence(); first thing after clicking the login button and I got the same error.

Comment: Did you found the solution to this issue?

Comment: It seems it's necessary to terminate the FirebaseFirestore.instance first.

Comment: following workrd for me,
`await FirebaseFirestore.instance.terminate();`
`await FirebaseFirestore.instance.clearPersistence();`

Answer (score 0):

add this to your Login Button 'onPressed':

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.terminate();
                FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .clearPersistence()
                    .then((value) => signinUser(email, password, context));
```

Answer (score 0):

For those you guys who use **bloc**/**cubit** with **.copyWith** on your *states*, ensure that your initial states starts with `SmartBloc.state.empty()`**.copyWith()** and not `SmartBloc.state`**.copyWith()** because that actually what I faced with when I think this is firestore persistance.